# Error: could not find function "TESTFUNC"

Tags: r

I'm an R noob with a Matlab backfround.

In RStudio I selected new R-Script.
I then cut and pasted some R code into the new R-script and saved it with a file name that is the same as the function name (as you would in Matlab).

I then input some test data and try to call the function:

```
TESTFUNC(0,y,x)
```

I then get the following error:

```
Error: could not find function "TESTFUNC"
```

Such an error in Matlab suggests that the file for "TESTFUNC" is stored in the wrong location? However I have no idea if this is the same case for R? Even if it is how can I find out what the correct location is? and how to I make move the file there?

Thanks

Baz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the code that declares the function in order to load it into memory for use. R does not pick up contents of folders without explicit command.

You can execute either of the following:

`TESTFUNC<-function(y,x){INSERT STUFF HERE}` or

`source("TESTFUNC.R")`

The first option runs the function directly, the second executes everything in the file TESTFUNC.R.  There is a third option of building a package, but I would forgo that for now.